# load long type column from parquet in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm trying to load a `parquet` file outputted by spark, from S3 into Athena. The structure of the parquet is this `[StructField(URI,StringType,true), StructField(LINK_ID,LongType,true)]`. So two fields the first one `string` the second one `long`. I'm trying to load this parquet into a table and I'm struggling to load the second field of type `long`. The integer options Athena gives me are `tinyint`, `int` and `bigint`. I would have expected that `bigint` would work, but it does not. When I query the table the second field is just empty.

here the whole query to create the table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.uri_to_link_id (
  `uri` string,
  `link_id` bigint 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://mybucket/parquet_file/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

is there anyway that I can load a long type field into Athena?

Answer (score 1):

I think when you convert data to parquet It convert to Struct. Are you try to print schema?

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "mydatabase", table_name = "test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
print(datasource0.printSchema())
```

If it show link_id like struct, you must use: 
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/resolve_choice.md